# MATLAB syntax errors

Tags: algorithm, matlab

```
function [S] = myExp(x)
x = linspace(0,1);
S = (1-(3*x/5)+(3*x.^2)/20-(x.^3/60))/(1+(2*x/5)+(x.^2/20));
    for i = 0:1
        x(i) = S(x(i));
    end
plot(x, x(i))
hold on
plot(x, exp(-x), '.-b')
end
```

I keep getting an error that indices must be real or positive, but I am not sure how to do this without effecting the linspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indexing with `i` equal to zero, which is not allowed.